# how to convert varchar2 to number in oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers, numbers, varchar

I have a table with many records and it continues to grow:

```
  table T_A
  { 
    total varchar2(10),
    total number
  }
```

The "total" field composed with 5 numbers and 1 character, e.g. "12345p", the character is either "p" or "N".

Now, I  want to write a trigger to convert existing "total" to numbers and store them in "total_num". furthermore, if there are inserting or updating operations, it can automatically finishes this conversion, and it must satisfy the following condition:

> if the character is "p", the number is positive, e.g. "12345p"
>   converts to "12345",   otherwise, the number is negative. e.g.
>   "12345N" converts to "-12345".

How to write this trigger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

(not tested as I don't have an oracle connection at the moment)

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ta_totals
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON T_A
  FOR EACH ROW

    DECLARE
        vnum number;
    BEGIN

    IF instr(:NEW.total,'p') > 0 THEN
       vnum:=TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(:NEW.total,0,LENGTH(:NEW.total)-1));     
    ELSIF instr(:NEW.total,'N') > 0 THEN
       vnum:=TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(:NEW.total,0,LENGTH(:NEW.total)-1))*-1;
    END IF; 

    :NEW.total_num := vnum; 

    END;
```

Comment: good for structure... OP may wish to do other checks if his data is dirtier than he thinks.. :)

Comment: Note that the OP's posted code has a lower case `p` and an upper case `N`: the `instr()` checks need to match the case.

Comment: +1 A subjective sidenote though: I find "IF :NEW.total like '%p%' THEN" much more in line with your intentions than using the INSTR operator.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted! Thanks everybody.